# Player Not jumping properly in Unity2d

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am a Unity Beginner and I'm practicing how to make games. I was creating a platformer that moves left right and jump, However with the code I have written I made it so the character jumps only when it touches the ground. However, it works but when it reaches the ground after finishing the first jump it takes a while before I can jump again. It seems like the function is not updating frequently in computer time.

Here is the code

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerScript : MonoBehaviour
{

    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    public float speed = 10f;
    public float jump = 20f;
    private Collider2D collide;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        collide = GetComponent<Collider2D>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
        {

            rb.velocity = new Vector2(1 * speed, rb.velocity.y);
            transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);
        }
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        {
            rb.velocity =new Vector2(-1 * speed, rb.velocity.y);
            transform.localScale = new Vector3(-1, 1, 1);
        }

        Jump();

    }

    private void OnCollisionStay2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if(collision.gameObject.tag == "Land")
        {
            Debug.Log("Touching Land");
            Jump();
        }
    }

    void Jump()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W))
       {
            rb.velocity = Vector2.up * jump;
            
       }
    }        
}
```

I tried adding a bool variable to indicate jump but still caused the same issue

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're checking input inside `Jump` inside a `OnCollisionStay2D`, which is happening in the physics update, and not updated every frame.

Add a boolean flag to check if player is grounded, and set it whenever he touches "Land."

Then, in the `Update` method, check for input and call `Jump`.

In the `Jump` method, add a check to see if the player is grounded.

```cs
private bool isGrounded = false;

private void OnCollisionStay2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if(collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Land"))
    {
         Debug.Log("Touching Land");
         isGrounded = true; // add a flag that player is grounded
    }
}

void Jump() {
    if (isGrounded) { // check isGrounded flag to allow jumping
        rb.velocity = Vector2.up * jump;
    }
}

private void Update() {
    // ...
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W)) {
        Jump(); // call jump when W is pressed
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Few things you can improve upon

1. Call the Jump function when the key is pressed and the grounded condition in true inside the FixedUpdate.
2. Use force rather than velocity for jump.
3. Use a Boolean as suggested in other answer for ground check. Also you need to reset the Boolean to false once the player has jumped.

Here is a [Unity Jump tutorial](https://vionixstudio.com/2021/10/26/how-to-make-a-character-jump-in-unity/) that explains all these in detail.